# Does Jaime Lannister have any claim to the Iron Throne?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The question is quite simple, **does Jaime Lannister have any claim to the Iron Throne? In other words, how far down in the succession is he?**

After all, his sister is currently the [Queen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133037/can-cersei-lannister-claim-the-iron-throne-and-legitimize-her-act), so if she dies, does he get the Throne? The succession is not quite [clear](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93775/succession-of-the-iron-throne-after-got-season-5-spoilers-whos-in-line), but Jaime is related to the current Queen and has the support of the Lannister armies (not so clear after the last episode though I have to admit).

A similar [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33653/why-didnt-jaime-lannister-succeed-aerys-targaryen-in-place-of-robert-baratheon) asks about why Jaime didn't get the Throne after killing the Mad King, which is a very different situation, so mine's not a dupe.

Comment: If the general populace is ok with officially declaring a dynasty switch, as they did with Robert, then yes; as the eldest son of the Lannister family, Jaime would have a claim to the throne.

Comment: I think a dynasty switch has happened already: from Targaryen to Baratheon, so that wouldn't be unheard of.

Comment: @Loki That switch was justified by the fact that Baratheons were descended from Targaryens. Lannisters have no such claim of descent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless Jaime is descended from a Targaryen king, he has no claim to the throne based on his blood. He is not a blood relation of the Targaryens to my best knowledge, so he is not in the line of succession.

The Baratheons are considered extinct (not counting the bastard son, Gendry). So if the direct Targaryen line is also broken, then a cadet branch of the Targaryen family would make a blood claim to the throne.

Cersei has no blood claim to the throne. She just happened to be the queen consort and queen mother of previous kings. But knowing Cersei, she wanted the throne, and she was not going to allow mere legalities get in the way. She probably coerced the Small Council and various lords to support her claim saying there was nobody else alive with a claim. (Notwithstanding Daenarys whom Cersei calls a usurper).

If Cersei was a legitimate queen and the line of succession was based solely on birth order (not just male heirs first), then Jaime would be next in line. He would inherit the throne if she died without living children.

Comment: +1. That's about right. Since it appears that a lot of people are confused about Cersei's _claim_ and that starts a huge debate always, pre-empting them, [here's the evidence for your statement](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133040/54887) `Cersei has no blood claim to the throne. She just happened to be the queen consort and queen mother of previous kings.`

Answer (score 0):

Cersei is only the Queen by claim of marriage to Robert Baratheon who's claim to the throne was by conquering and by a partial blood connection to Targaryen line. Jamie has no connection to that line and would not currently be the heir to throne.

But arguably Cersei has very little claim as well but as she declared herself Queen and had little resistance it was allowed by most.

He could potential have a claim with Cersei now openly showing off their relationship and they could have a marriage and they might be able to name him the king.

Comment: Marrying the queen would make him Prince Consort. King would require they go through another Coronation to somehow openly transfer or share power.

Comment: No, Cersei was Queen Regent for that fact (given that Joffrey was too young to rule when Robert passed), she is Queen because she *took* the Iron Throne for herself, thereby making it hers *by right of conquest*. Still puts Jaime in line because he was relinquished from his position as Kingsguard though.

Comment: [No Cersei is not a legitimate Queen....Nor does she get a claim by virtue of being Dowager Queen of Robert Baratheon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133040/54887)

Answer (score -1):

Folks forget, but Jaime has previously taken a vow as a Kingsguard. Notwithstanding the fact that he has broken that vow more than once, legally it means he has forsaken the right to hold land and titles outside those accorded to the Kingsguard (e.g. "ser" or "lord commander of the kings guard").

Regardless of Cersei's position, Jaime has no *legal* claim. That doesn't seem to stop folks in Westeros, of course, but there it is.

Comment: In the show, Tommen relinquished Jaime of that duty.

Comment: @Möoz but did not place him in the line of succession and did not name him Lord of Casterly Rock or anything else.